# oncanplay vs. oncanplaythrough

Tags: javascript, audio, stream

Both work in the code.
Which should be used?

A radio stream would be considered what?
http://hi5.1980s.fm/;

**oncanplay**

https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/142/

> The canplay event is fired when the user agent can play the media, but
>   estimates that not enough data has been loaded to play the media up to
>   its end without having to stop for further buffering of content.
>
> The browser can play the media, but estimates that not enough data has
>   been loaded to play the media up to its end without having to stop for
>   further buffering of content.

```
player.oncanplay = function () {
        if (value.value !== "") {
            canPlay = true;
            playPauseIcon(true);
        }
    };
```

**oncanplaythrough**

https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/144/

> The canplaythrough event is fired when the user agent can play the
>   media and estimates that enough data has been loaded to play the media
>   up to its end without having to stop for further buffering of content.
>
> The browser estimates it can play the media up to its end without
>   stopping for content buffering.

```
player.oncanplaythrough = function () {
        if (value.value !== "") {
            canPlay = true;
            playPauseIcon(true);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oncanplay`. But in some web-browsers it is not reliable, so usually, people use both events.

Because both events are fired when `readyState` did change, you can use `player.readyState` to determine a current state and decide what to do if events happen before you set listeners.

[html.spec media page url](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#event-media-canplay)

Comment: Can you show me how I can implement that in the code please? How would I use both events in the code? Can you provide a jsfiddle with the code using both?

Comment: Can you provide an updated jsfiddle with player.readyState in the code? And thank you for the information. https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/142/

Comment: @MaryJaneSmith Yes i'll try to provide an example for you soon. This is my first answer :)

Comment: @MaryJaneSmith check this https://codepen.io/arturparkhisenko/pen/qLygVo I've simplified code example with a changed naming a little bit (mostly about canPlay, because we have it, in fact, you can check if a browser can play a provided source by type). I've left a note about a more robust solution (it's like u set all events, then u filter them by groups, and in the end, u trigger some checks and update your variables and UI state).

Comment: Can you provide an updated jsfiddle with that code in it please? https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/142/

Comment: How would I add that to my code here? https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/142/ Could you update the jsfiddle code with the answer you provided.

Comment: @MaryJaneSmith yes, no problem. Few mins.

Comment: @MaryJaneSmith added multiple events and moved one check https://jsfiddle.net/Lyj70doe/

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have a question? How would I convert this to for loop? playingEvents.forEach(function I tried doing it here, but I got stuck on it. https://jsfiddle.net/Lyj70doe/12/

Comment: @arturparkhisenko 'in some web-browsers it is not reliable' - Which browsers?

Comment: @sol I met problems with an Edge 17. Check these issues, some of them with labels like [won't fix]. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11459883/ , https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19031378/

Answer (score 0):

`oncanplaythrough` is the browsers estimation that enough of the media has loaded to be able to play all the way through.

`oncanplay` is if any media has loaded, but may result in jerky playback.

Both can be used to trigger playback but infer different meaning. MDN is a great resource for clarification.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oncanplaythrough

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oncanplay

Comment: Would you be able to provide an updated jsfiddle with player.readyState in the code? Where both oncanplaythrough and oncanplay are used? And thank you for the information. https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/142/

Comment: You would complicate things by using both. I'd pick one that best fits your situation and run with it. In this case I'd go with `oncanplaythrough`. If you want to get really fancy you could send the total bytes to load from the server prior to loading, and get the frontend to estimate how quickly bytes are coming through. Enabling you to make your own decision about `can play` status, but it's a massive undertaking.

Comment: What if I used both of them? ["canplay", "canplaythrough"]; https://jsfiddle.net/spaozyxq/42/ So, if one doesn't work in a browser, the other one will. Is that a good idea, a good way to do it?

Comment: `canplay` would win. Support is fairly wide spread https://caniuse.com/#feat=stream The main browser lacking is IE11, but most users should be moving Edge. Check you analytics and see what proportion of users use IE 11 and decide if you can live without it's support

Comment: What's the difference between canplay and oncanplay?

Comment: This code uses oncanplay: https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/142/ This code uses canplay: https://jsfiddle.net/spaozyxq/46/